# How to mock the read file function using unittest

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I want to mock the read file method using `unittest`. Need to test read_file() method from the read class.
having below class:

```
class read:
     def read_file():
        result = None
        if os.path.isfile("c:/user/file.txt"):
            result = []
            try:
                file = open("c:/user/file.txt", "r")
                file.close()
            except Exception as e:
                raise error(f"reading file error{"c:/user/file.txt"} - {e}")
        else:
            raise error(f"no such file error{"c:/user/file.txt"}""")
        return result
```

Tried test for read_file() method:

```
def test_read_file():

    read_file=[
        "20000, 00000000, 10000, xyz"
    ]
    mock_open = mock.mock_open(read_data=read_file)
    with mock.patch("builtins.open", mock_open):
        reader = read("filename")
        exp_result = read_file()
    assert read_file == exp_result
```

Comment: try like thismock.patch("your_dotted_path_to_the_func_where_you_using_open_method.open", mock_open)

Comment: Failed, got error here `mock_open = mock.mock_open(read_data=read_file)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The class `read`

There are some errors in your class `read`, so I have made the minimum corrections to it and after that I have saved the class `read` in a file called read.py. The file `read.py` is as below:

```
import os

class read:

    #++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    # Add this method to your class
    #++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    # ---> I have add the argument self in the method because it is necessary
    # when you define the method of a class
    def read_file(self):
        result = None
        # ---> the path of the file 'file.txt' is saved in
        # the attribute self.filename
        if os.path.isfile(self.filename):
            result = []
            try:
                file = open(self.filename, "r")
                file.close()
            except Exception as e:
                # ----> raise Exception and not 'error'
                raise Exception(f"reading file error{self.filename} - {e}")
        else:
            # ----> raise Exception and not 'error'
            raise Exception(f"no such file error {self.filename}")
        return result
```

**Note** that I have add the method `__init__` to it.
To try to execute the method `read_file()` you can use the following code (write it in the same file `read.py`):

```
try:
    file_content = read("c:/user/file.txt").read_file()
    print(file_content)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

If the file `c:/user/file.txt` exists you will obtain the following output (empty list because you have set `result = []`):

```
[]
```

If the file `c:/user/file.txt` doesn't exist you will obtain the following error message (print by the instruction `print(ex)`):

```
no such file error c:/user/file.txt
```

### The test file

I write a possible test for the method `read_file()` of the class `read` in a file called `test_read.py` saved in the same folder which contains the file `read.py`. The content of the file `test_read.py` is:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from read import read

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    # ---> here yor test with a bit changes <---
    def test_read_file(self):
        read_file = [
            "20000, 00000000, 10000, xyz"
        ]
        # instantiation of the class read
        reader = read("filename")
        # patching of the method 'read_file'
        with patch.object(reader, 'read_file') as mock_read_file:
            # set the return value of the read_file
            mock_read_file.return_value = read_file
            # call the method read_file()
            exp_result = reader.read_file()
            # check the result
            assert read_file == exp_result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The test patches the method `read_file()` setting its return value to the list `["20000, 00000000, 10000, xyz"]`, so when the method `read_file()` is executed by the instruction `reader.read_file()` it returns exactly that list as the test is expecting.

To execute the previous test do the following steps:

```
# go to the folder where are present the 2 files (read.py and test_read.py)
cd path/to/folder/with/file/test_read.py

# execute the followed command
python -m unittest discover -v
```

The output of the test execution is:

```
no such file error c:/user/file.txt
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

I hope I have guessed your intentions.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer, Can we do it using pytest ?

Comment: @jhonD You can do with pytest, but I don't use it so I can't help.

Comment: I ran the answer for the function and tried to get the coverage but that function still in `RED` So, is mocked function not cover in coverage?

Comment: @jhonD go by cd command in the folder where you have saved the 2 files `read.py` and `test_read.py`. After that try to use the following command: `python -m unittest discover -v`

Comment: @jhonD I have modified my answer with the run instructions. I have noted that actually the method `read_file()` is executed (see the message `no such file error c:/user/file.txt` in the output showed in the answer) and the patch set only its return value to your desidered list.

Comment: I ran the same but still not clear how to cover it in coverage report. How to get 100% coverage of it

Comment: Ok I agree with you, I have executed the 2 commands: `python -m coverage run -m unittest` and `python -m coverage report` and I don't get 100% of coverage. I don't know coverage but I think that its report means that not all the instructions of read.py and test_read.py are executed. May be we need other tests to reach 100%. See at [this link](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-unit-testing/python-unittest-coverage/)